# Data driven not working in webdriver/java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I've tried till here, but unable to think how to call cell content in the below code, to register under a site : http://newtours.demoaut.com/mercuryregister.php

```
public class DataDriven {
    static WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
    public static void openurl() throws InterruptedException{
        driver.get("http://newtours.demoaut.com/");
        driver.wait(100);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }
public static void register() throws Exception{
    FileInputStream fi=new FileInputStream("E:\\datadriven.ods");
    Workbook wb = Workbook.getWorkbook(fi);
    Sheet sh=wb.getSheet(0);
    driver.get("http://newtours.demoaut.com/");
    driver.wait(100);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/a"));
    driver.wait(100);

}

public static void getCelldata(){
    Cell=
}
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Hi, could you please help me how to get cell data in the above script using datadriven frame work

Answer (score 0):

Use POI jars Use getXLcellValue function to get the value in excel Use setXLCellValue function to set the value in excel

Parameters :-

- xlpath -> Location of your Excel file
- sheetName -> Sheet name in your Excel File
- rowNum and cellNum -> Row and column number where your data is
  present

  ```
       public String getXLcellValue(String xlpath, String sheetName, int rowNum, int cellNum)
          {
              try{
                  FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(xlpath);

                  Workbook wb=WorkbookFactory.create(fis);


          return wb.getSheet(sheetName).getRow(rowNum).getCell(cellNum).getStringCellValue();

  }
  catch(Exception ex)
  {
      Log.info("Error in getXLcellValue ="+ ex.getMessage());
  }
          return "";
  ```

  }

  ```
  //set the value of the cell present in specific sheet
  ```

void setXLCellValue(String xlpath,String sheetName,int rowNum,int cellNum, String input)
    {
        try{
            FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(xlpath);

```
        Workbook wb=WorkbookFactory.create(fis);

        wb.getSheet(sheetName).getRow(rowNum).createCell(cellNum).setCellValue(input);

        FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream(xlpath);lpath);

        wb.write(fos);

        fos.close();

        Log.info("Set the value in cell(setXLCellValue)");

    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Log.info("Error in setXLCellValue ="+ ex.getMessage());
            }

        }
```

Hope it will help you :)